# Creating numerical right triangle using nested loop

Tags: loops, for-loop, nested

I'm new to programming and this nesting using loops confuses me a little bit.
I would like to create this shape but getting confused in for loops.

```
---------1
--------22
-------333
------4444
-----55555
----666666
```

Any tips on how to get comfortable with creating different shapes using nested for loops will be appreciated.Thanks.

Comment: I won't do your homework, sorry.

Comment: It's not homework.I'm actually studying for the quiz.

Comment: Why don't you show us what code you've tried or what code you need explanation on.

Answer (score 0):

Logic:

```
for(int i=1;i<=n;i++) {
    for(int j=n-i; j!=0; j--) {
         System.out.print("-");
    }
    System.out.println(i);
}
```